# How to execute the output of a command within the current shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe

I'm well aware of the `source` (aka `.`) utility, which will take the contents from a file and execute them within the current shell.

Now, I'm transforming some text into shell commands, and then running them, as follows:

```
$ ls | sed ... | sh
```

`ls` is just a random example, the original text can be anything. `sed` too, just an example for transforming text. The interesting bit is `sh`. I pipe whatever I got to `sh` and it runs it.

My problem is, that means starting a new sub shell. I'd rather have the commands run within my current shell. Like I would be able to do with `source some-file`, if I had the commands in a text file.

I don't want to create a temp file because feels dirty.

Alternatively, I'd like to start my sub shell with the exact same characteristics as my current shell.

#### update

Ok, the solutions using backtick certainly work, but I often need to do this while I'm checking and changing the output, so I'd much prefer if there was a way to pipe the result into something in the end.

#### sad update

Ah, the `/dev/stdin` thing looked so pretty, but, in a more complex case, it didn't work.

So, I have this:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.doc' | ack -v '\.doc$' | perl -pe 's/^((.*)\.doc)$/git mv -f $1 $2.doc/i' | source /dev/stdin
```

Which ensures all `.doc` files have their extension lowercased.

And which incidentally, can be handled with `xargs`, but that's besides the point.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.doc' | ack -v '\.doc$' | perl -pe 's/^((.*)\.doc)$/$1 $2.doc/i' | xargs -L1 git mv
```

So, when I run the former, it'll exit right away, nothing happens.

Comment: Does your complex command work when you pipe to a temp file first and then source it?  If not, what's the problem with the generated output?  The output of your command won't work if your filenames have spaces in them or if certain sequences aren't escaped properly.  I'd want to add quotes around $1 and $2.doc at a minimum.

Comment: Is there any good reason for having to run this in the original shell ? - these examples doesn't manipulate the current shell so you gain nothing by doing so. The quick solution is you redirect output to a file and source that file though

Comment: @kaleb the output runs fine. in this particular case, even if i pipe to sh. the file names are space-safe, but thanks for noting.

@nos git environment variables on the original shell. and again, these are just examples. the question is for life.

Comment: source /dev/stdin didn't work for me when needing assigned variables to stick around.
geirha on freenode bash pointed me to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 and suggested I try a process substitution
source <(command)
which worked for me

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
$ ls | sed ... | source /dev/stdin
```

**UPDATE:** This works in bash 4.0, as well as tcsh, and dash (if you change `source` to `.`).  Apparently this was buggy in bash 3.2.  From the [bash 4.0 release notes](http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg04800.html):

> Fixed a bug that caused `.' to fail to read and execute commands from non-regular files such as devices or named pipes.

Comment: Oh, and since you're listing the shells, it works in zsh too.

Comment: I thought this was ingenious until I tried it in msys/mingw (where there is no /dev folder (or even devices)! I tried many combinations of eval, $(), and backticks ``. I couldn't make anything work, so I finally just redirected output into a temp file, sourced the temp file, and the removed it.  Basically "sed ... > /tmp/$$.tmp && . /tmp/$$.tmp && rm /tmp/$$.tmp".  Anybody got a msys/mingw solution without temp files???

Comment: Just a remark: This one does not seem to handle export statements as expected. If the piped string has an export statement, the exportet variable is not available in your terminal environment afterwards, whereas with eval export also works perfectly.

Comment: In bash without the lastpipe option set, this creates a subshell just like `| bash` would

Comment: Given that MacOS X usually has bash 3.2 (maybe Yosemite has 4.0?), and the need for lastpipe trickery in my use case (exporting all the variables in a file by pre-processing each line with sed to add 'export ') I chose to go with the `eval "$(sed ...)"` approach - but thanks for the 3.2 bug heads-up!

Comment: @AlexDupuy nope, Yosemite still provides the old `3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)`.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the source is executed in a subshell and thus the values are lost at the invoking shell
this variation tho worked for me `source <(sed ...)`  ... but now I see that it was already given here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22233248/652904 by @rishta

Answer (score 159):

The `eval` command exists for this very purpose.

```
eval "$( ls | sed... )"
```

More from the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> **eval**
>
> ```
>           eval [arguments]
> ```
>
> The arguments are concatenated together
>   into a single command, which
>   is then read and executed, and its
>   exit status returned as the exit
>   status of eval. If there are no
>   arguments or only empty arguments, the
>   return status is zero.

Comment: The only issue here is that you may need to insert ;'s to separate your commands.  I use this method myself to work on AIX, Sun, HP, and Linux.

Comment: Tanktalus, thanks for that comment, it just made my script work. On my machine eval does not separate commands on newlines and using source does not work even with semi-colons. Eval with semi-colons is the solution. I wish I could give you some points.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov: I ranked him up for you ;-)

Comment: This is excellent. However, for my use case, I ended up having to put quotes around my $(), like so: `eval "$( ssh remote-host 'cat ~/.bash_profile' )"` Note that I am indeed using bash 3.2.

Comment: This works for me where the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 52):

Try using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), which replaces output of a command with a temporary file which can then be sourced:

```
source <(echo id)
```

Comment: Which kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: This was my first thought as well. Though I like the eval solution better. @PauloTorrens <(xyz)  simply executes xyz and replaces <(xyz) with the name of a file that will write the output of xyz. It's really easy to understand how this works by doing for example: `echo <(echo id)`, giving the output `/dev/fd/12` (12 is an example), `cat <(echo id)`, giving the output`id`, and then `source <(echo id)` giving the same output as simply writing `id`

Comment: @PauloTorrens, this is called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).  See linked docs for official explanation, but the short answer is that "<()" is a special syntax that was designed for cases like this in mind.

Comment: @MarkStosberg, do you know if this is a special syntax, or just a subshell `(...)` redirected?

Comment: @PauloTorrens, It is a special syntax just for process substitution.

Comment: I'm from the future and this is still the best solution. Clear, short, simple and free of side effects. Specially now that backticks are considered obsolete and anti-pattern.

Comment: I prefer `. <(echo id)`, which does the same thing with less typing.

Comment: This can set variables in the current environment, and it executes multiple lines of code. For my use case, this makes it better than the top or accepted answer. But in some situations, this may not be ideal.

Answer (score 43):

Wow, I know this is an old question, but I've found myself with the same exact problem recently (that's how I got here).

Anyway - I don't like the `source /dev/stdin` answer, but I think I found a better one. It's deceptively simple actually:

```
echo ls -la | xargs xargs
```

Nice, right? Actually, this still doesn't do what you want, because if you have multiple lines it will concat them into a single command instead of running each command separately. So the solution I found is:

```
ls | ... | xargs -L 1 xargs
```

the `-L 1` option means you use (at most) 1 line per command execution. **Note:** if your line ends with a trailing space, it will be concatenated with the next line! So make sure each line ends with a non-space.

Finally, you can do

```
ls | ... | xargs -L 1 xargs -t
```

to see what commands are executed (-t is verbose).

Hope someone reads this!

Answer (score 8):

```
`ls | sed ...`
```

I sort of feel like `ls | sed ... | source -` would be prettier, but unfortunately `source` doesn't understand `-` to mean `stdin`.

Comment: after seeing mark4o's answer, doesn't it feel like it was right in our faces all this time?

Comment: Heh, yeah.  I never remember that that stuff exists.

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is "the right answer" to the question:

```
ls | sed ... | while read line; do $line; done
```

That is, one can pipe into a `while` loop; the `read` command command takes one line from its `stdin` and assigns it to the variable `$line`. `$line` then becomes the command executed within the loop; and it continues until there are no further lines in its input.

This still won't work with some control structures (like another loop), but it fits the bill in this case.

Answer (score 2):

To use the mark4o's solution on bash 3.2 (macos) a here string can be used instead of pipelines like in this example:

```
. /dev/stdin <<< "$(grep '^alias' ~/.profile)"
```

Comment: or use backticks:  
  
    . /dev/stdin <<< \`grep '^alias' ~/.profile`

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is command substitution with backticks: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html

See section 3.4.5

Comment: If you're using bash the `$( )` syntax might be preferred. 'Course backticks work in *more* shells...

Comment: $(command) and $((1+1)) work in all posix shells.
I think many are put off by vim marking them as syntax errors, but that's just because vim is highlighting for the original Bourne shell which very few use. To get vim to highlight correctly put this in your .vimrc:

    let g:is_posix = 1

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `source` then?

```
$ ls | sed ... > out.sh ; source out.sh
```

Comment: He mentioned that temp files are icky.