# How can I pass my input token to a nested command in a zsh alias

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

I have this zsh alias:

`alias ogf="source <(clone_git_file -ts $1)"`

`clone_git_file -ts` returns a string which can be executed in a shell. Using `source <(...)` works perfectly (executes the code in my current shell), but I can't get the `$1` token to be passed into the nested command.

I found the `source` usage above [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22233248) by the way.

How can I achieve this, passing in the token correctly? If I remove the `source <(` from my alias and do this:

`source <(ogf my_url)`

`my_url` is passed along and everything works perfectly.

Comment: That's not an alias. Use a function.

Comment: It *is* an alias; it just doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases don't take arguments. The `$1` is expanded when you define the alias. You want to use a function instead.

```
ogf () {
    source <(clone_git_file -ts "$1")
}
```

---

It's also not simply a matter of preventing `$1` from being expanded immediately; if you tried

```
alias ogf='source <(clone_git_file -ts $1)'
```

then `ogf foo` would expand to `ogf $1 foo`, with `$1` being expanded to whatever the current shell's value of `$1` is.

Comment: This fixes one problem, but causes another. The `source <()` part doesn't work. Change the nested method to `echo "time"` and try it yourself, no output. Do you know how to solve that? Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: `source <(echo "time")` runs the time pre-command modifier for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, does that mean you get the output just the same as if you had typed `time` in the shell instead?

Comment: You know what, I don't know what I did wrong but it is working now. Thank you!